# compare 256 bit Hexadecimal stored in string

Tags: c++

I have two Hexadecimal number stored in two separate string variables. I must compare this strings so I can find the smallest.

```
string text = "Hello world!";
string temp;
string hash;
string target;


for(int nonce=0;nonce<1235;nonce++){ 
    temp = text + to_string(nonce);
    hash=sha256(temp);
    if(...)
    return temp;
}
```

In the if-statement I should add something like "if (hash <= target) do this..". Anyone has solution?

Comment: Have you tried `if (hash <= target)` yet?

Comment: I'd make a function for the comparison, with the folowing logic : if string 2 is shorter (length) than string 1, return true, if string 1 is shorter than string 2, return false. Else (same lenght) compare the first char (or the 3rd if you have a 0x prefix) of each string. Smallest char implies smallest hex, thanks to ascii values. Finally, if both first chars are the same, recursive call to the same function with the same strings WITHOUT the first char

Comment: seems legit :D I rembembered string comparison worked  in terms of lenght of string but I was wrong. Do you know how can I store a 256 bit Hexadecimal on integer variable?

Comment: @Giuseppe - store a 256 bit is easy having an unsigned 128 bit integer type but, as far as I know, C++ standard (C++11, at least) ensure you only a 64 unsigned integer.